# Why is for loop iterated only once?

Tags: python, loops, file, for-loop

I'm rather new to coding, yet as I have to write a few letters I wanted to write a script to change the name within this letter automatically.

I've got a textfile with placeholders for the name and a csv-file where the names are stored in the following format:

```
Surname;Firstname
Doe;John
Norris;Chuck
...
```

Now I've conjured up this script:

```
import csv
import re

letterPATH = "Brief.txt"
tablePATH = "Liste.csv"


with open(letterPATH, "r") as letter, open(tablePATH, "r") as table:
    table = csv.reader(table, delimiter=";")
    rows = list(table)
    rows = rows[1::]
    print(rows)
    for (surname, firstname) in rows:
        #Check if first- and surname have correct output
        #print(firstname)
        #print(surname)

        for lines in letter:
            new_content = ""
            print(lines)
            lines = re.sub(r"\<Nachname\>", surname, lines)
            print(lines)
            lines = re.sub(r"\<Vorname\>", firstname, lines)
            print(lines)
            new_content += lines
        with open(surname + firstname +".txt", "w") as new_letter:
            new_letter.writelines(new_content)
```

I've got the following problem now:
There's a file created a textfile for each entry as it should (JohnDoe.txt, ChuckNorris.txt and so on) however only the first file has the correct content, while the others are empty.

While debugging I've seen that the for-loop in line 18 is only iterated once and the with statement is iterated multiple times as it should.
I simply do not understand why the for-loop isn't iterating.

Cheers and thanks for your help! :)

Comment: After you've read all of the lines in `letter` during the first iteration of the loop, *you are at the end of that file* - further reads will return nothing, because there is nothing further to read.  You need to rewind the file each time (`letter.seek(0)`), or read the entire file into a list one time, before the loop starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letter` is a file. A file keeps track of how much you've read and where the next read should be. So if you've read two lines, then the next read will be on the third line, and so on.

Since you read through the whole file the first time, the next iterations it'll not read any more lines from the file, since you've already read them.

The solution could be to reset the file pointer (the thing pointing to where in the file you've currently read to) to the beginning with the `letter.seek(0)` method. Or, you could simply store the file content in a list directly and iterate over the list.

```
import csv
import re

letterPATH = "Brief.txt"
tablePATH = "Liste.csv"


with open(letterPATH, "r") as letter_file, open(tablePATH, "r") as table:
    table = csv.reader(table, delimiter=";")
    letter = list(letter_file)  # Add all content to a list instead.
    rows = list(table)
    rows = rows[1::]
    print(rows)
    for (surname, firstname) in rows:
        #Check if first- and surname have correct output
        #print(firstname)
        #print(surname)

        for lines in letter:
            new_content = ""
            print(lines)
            lines = re.sub(r"\<Nachname\>", surname, lines)
            print(lines)
            lines = re.sub(r"\<Vorname\>", firstname, lines)
            print(lines)
            new_content += lines
        with open(surname + firstname +".txt", "w") as new_letter:
            new_letter.writelines(new_content)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a similar idea tbh but I didn't know how to handle it :D